# Comparing and deleting similar strings within a vector

Tags: java, string, vector

JAVA: First off, Thanks so much for taking the time to look at my question; your help is EXTREMELY appreciated!

So, the problem is i have a Vector of Objects in Java and each object has a name(String). But, i have tons of objects that are repeated, and the ones that are repeated are always directly after the Object they repeat. Also the number of repeats ranges from 1-10(So frustrating) its completely random.

How would i go about deleting the repeats, I thought about comparing each objects name with the next in the vector and deleting all of the ones that match but that gave me tons of problems. Thank you SO much for your help in advance!

-Dylan

EDIT: Just to make sure you understand the kind of repetition i'm talking about ive added this.

Vector

---Object1(String name = "hi") --> Remove This one.

---Object2(String name = "hi")

---Object3(string name = "bob")

End Vector

Edit 2: add Code

```
public class Vector
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Person person1 = new Person("jane");
  Person person2 = new Person("jane");
  Person person3 = new Person("bob");
  Person person4 = new Person("shelly");

  Vector<Person> vectorObject = new Vector<Person>
  vectorObject.add(person1);
  vectorObject.add(person2);
  vectorObject.add(person3);
  vectorObject.add(person4);

 }
}
class Person
{
 String name = null;
 String bDay = null;
 String color = null;
 public Person(String name)
 {
      this.name = name;
     }



}
```

Comment: What language? What does your code look like?

Comment: okay one moment, lol ive got to get it up.

Comment: Is there a reason that multiple copies of the same person are added to the Vector? If you are deliberately doing this, you might consider using a Set instead which will automagically ignore inserting duplicates. If you are not, then you have bigger worries than getting rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know which language are you using, so I will give you an algorithm in JavaScript:

```
var newvector=new Array();
var lastName;
for(var i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
   if(!lastName || vector[i].name!=lastName){
      lastName=vector[i].name;
      newvector.push(vector[i]);
   }
}
```

The problem is that this way a new vector is created, and if the original one is huge maybe you will have memory problems.

Comment: I don't know Java, so I can't adapt my algorithm to Java, sorry.

Comment: If i may ask why do you increment i within the for loop even though the for loop does it for you? is that part of the algorithm?

Comment: @Dylan That was because I started writing it as a while loop, but I'm sure I deleted it after converting to a for loop. I don't understand how it came back, haha.

Comment: Lol, okay thank you so much. From what little i understand of javaScript i believe i can make this work in java as well. That last increment was just throwing me off. Im off to test it and see if it solves my problem, Brb.

Comment: Thank You this Worked once i changed everything over to java!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should use a different data structure.

You may want to use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a Vector. Sets do not contain duplicate elements. You've to override `equals(Object)` method.

Or use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the name property as key value and store the corresponding Person object as value.

In both cases you prevent duplicates rather then deleting them afterwards.

```
  Person person1 = new Person("jane");
  Person person2 = new Person("jane");
  Person person3 = new Person("bob");
  Person person4 = new Person("shelly");

  Map<String, Person> nameToPerson = new HashMap<>();
  nameToPerson.add(person1.name, person1);
  nameToPerson.add(person2.name, person2);
  nameToPerson.add(person3.name, person3);
  nameToPerson.add(person4.name, person4);

  Collection<Person> noDuplicatesHere = map.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your first problem:

```
class Person 
{
    String name = null;
    String bDay = null;
    String color = null;
    public Person(String name)
    {
        name = this.name;
    }
}
```

it should be:

```
class Person 
{
    String name = null;
    String bDay = null;
    String color = null;
    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here is more info on the `this` keyword:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Your second problem is: I'm guessing you are trying to create a Vector, java.util.Vector to be exact. If you create a new instance of Vector inside of a class called vector, it will create a new instance of itself, not of java.util.Vector. You can either rename the class or you can just do:

```
java.util.Vector<Person> vector = new java.util.Vector<Person>();
```

if you want to compare 2 string values use:

```
String name = "John";
String name2 = "Joe";
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(name2))
    System.out.println("They match!");
```

You can also just use equals() if you want an exact match.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the first problem. But what i am actually looking for is a good algorithm to use to compare the previous name with the current one and if they match, delete the previous one. Thank you for your answer but i assumed i was going to have to use the String.equals() method.